# Adding .jar files in docker image

Tags: docker, solr, jar

Hi I have am using the solr dockerfile and adding a .jar file with it and creating the docker image.

This is the .jar file I have been trying to add into my docker image

```
ARG JAR_FILE=target/jts-core-1.15.0-javadoc.jar
ADD  ${JAR_FILE} /server/solr-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/testing.jar
```

Below is my docker-file which I have been using to create, I have also added a volume to persist the data. When i build the docker image it adds .jar file into my specified path. However, it removes all the other jar files that were created within the default solr dockerfile.

What could i add in the dockerfile so that it add the new .jar file and also contain the already created .jar files

```
FROM openjdk:11-jre

LABEL maintainer="Project Ranger team <mbyousaf@deloitte.co.uk>"
LABEL repository="https://github.com/docker-solr/docker-solr"

ARG SOLR_VERSION="8.5.2"
#ARG SOLR_SHA512="0a43401ecf7946b2724da2d43896cd505386a8f9b07ddc60256cb586873e7e58610d2c34b1cf797323bf06c7613b109527a15105dc2a11be6f866531a1f2cef6"
ARG SOLR_SHA512="02b9b90468f399701dba26695c9af6cd205f47916a06e26838613fe238594e9902de6ef3b42ec8257d195e37589adf8427d9b7962557731e91949fbef06bb544"
#ARG SOLR_KEYS="E58A6F4D5B2B48AC66D5E53BD4F181881A42F9E6"
ARG SOLR_KEYS="86EDB9C33B8517228E88A8F93E48C0C6EF362B9E"
# If specified, this will override SOLR_DOWNLOAD_SERVER and all ASF mirrors. Typically used downstream for custom builds
ARG SOLR_DOWNLOAD_URL

# Override the solr download location with e.g.:
#   docker build -t mine --build-arg SOLR_DOWNLOAD_SERVER=http://www-eu.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr .
ARG SOLR_DOWNLOAD_SERVER

USER root
# Add Tini
ENV TINI_VERSION v0.18.0
ADD https://github.com/krallin/tini/releases/download/${TINI_VERSION}/tini /tini
RUN chmod +x /tini

RUN microdnf --setopt=tsflags=nodocs install -y acl dirmngr gnupg lsof procps wget && microdnf clean all;\
  cd /usr/local/bin; wget -nv https://github.com/apangin/jattach/releases/download/v1.5/jattach; chmod 755 jattach; \
  echo >jattach.sha512 "d8eedbb3e192a8596c08efedff99b9acf1075331e1747107c07cdb1718db2abe259ef168109e46bd4cf80d47d43028ff469f95e6ddcbdda4d7ffa73a20e852f9  jattach"; \
  sha512sum -c jattach.sha512; rm jattach.sha512

ENV SOLR_USER="solr" \
    SOLR_UID="8983" \
    SOLR_GROUP="solr" \
    SOLR_GID="8983" \
    SOLR_CLOSER_URL="http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua?filename=lucene/solr/$SOLR_VERSION/solr-$SOLR_VERSION.tgz&action=download" \
    SOLR_DIST_URL="https://www.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/$SOLR_VERSION/solr-$SOLR_VERSION.tgz" \
    SOLR_ARCHIVE_URL="https://archive.apache.org/dist/lucene/solr/$SOLR_VERSION/solr-$SOLR_VERSION.tgz" \
    PATH="/opt/solr/bin:/opt/docker-solr/scripts:$PATH" \
    SOLR_INCLUDE=/etc/default/solr.in.sh \
    SOLR_HOME=/var/solr/data \
    SOLR_PID_DIR=/var/solr \
    SOLR_LOGS_DIR=/var/solr/logs \
    LOG4J_PROPS=/var/solr/log4j2.xml

RUN set -ex; \
  groupadd -r --gid "$SOLR_GID" "$SOLR_GROUP"; \
  useradd -r --uid "$SOLR_UID" --gid "$SOLR_GID" "$SOLR_USER"


RUN set -ex; \
  export GNUPGHOME="/tmp/gnupg_home"; \
  mkdir -p "$GNUPGHOME"; \
  chmod 700 "$GNUPGHOME"; \
  echo "disable-ipv6" >> "$GNUPGHOME/dirmngr.conf"; \
  for key in $SOLR_KEYS; do \
    found=''; \
    for server in \
      ha.pool.sks-keyservers.net \
      hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 \
      hkp://p80.pool.sks-keyservers.net:80 \
      pgp.mit.edu \
    ; do \
      echo "  trying $server for $key"; \
      gpg --batch --keyserver "$server" --keyserver-options timeout=10 --recv-keys "$key" && found=yes && break; \
      gpg --batch --keyserver "$server" --keyserver-options timeout=10 --recv-keys "$key" && found=yes && break; \
    done; \
    test -z "$found" && echo >&2 "error: failed to fetch $key from several disparate servers -- network issues?" && exit 1; \
  done; \
  exit 0

RUN set -ex; \
  export GNUPGHOME="/tmp/gnupg_home"; \
  MAX_REDIRECTS=1; \
  if [ -n "$SOLR_DOWNLOAD_URL" ]; then \
    # If a custom URL is defined, we download from non-ASF mirror URL and allow more redirects and skip GPG step
    # This takes effect only if the SOLR_DOWNLOAD_URL build-arg is specified, typically in downstream Dockerfiles
    MAX_REDIRECTS=4; \
    SKIP_GPG_CHECK=true; \
  elif [ -n "$SOLR_DOWNLOAD_SERVER" ]; then \
    SOLR_DOWNLOAD_URL="$SOLR_DOWNLOAD_SERVER/$SOLR_VERSION/solr-$SOLR_VERSION.tgz"; \
  fi; \
  for url in $SOLR_DOWNLOAD_URL $SOLR_CLOSER_URL $SOLR_DIST_URL $SOLR_ARCHIVE_URL; do \
    if [ -f "/opt/solr-$SOLR_VERSION.tgz" ]; then break; fi; \
    echo "downloading $url"; \
    if wget -t 10 --max-redirect $MAX_REDIRECTS --retry-connrefused -nv "$url" -O "/opt/solr-$SOLR_VERSION.tgz"; then break; else rm -f "/opt/solr-$SOLR_VERSION.tgz"; fi; \
  done; \
  if [ ! -f "/opt/solr-$SOLR_VERSION.tgz" ]; then echo "failed all download attempts for solr-$SOLR_VERSION.tgz"; exit 1; fi; \
  if [ -z "$SKIP_GPG_CHECK" ]; then \
    echo "downloading $SOLR_ARCHIVE_URL.asc"; \
    wget -nv "$SOLR_ARCHIVE_URL.asc" -O "/opt/solr-$SOLR_VERSION.tgz.asc"; \
    echo "$SOLR_SHA512 */opt/solr-$SOLR_VERSION.tgz" | sha512sum -c -; \
    (>&2 ls -l "/opt/solr-$SOLR_VERSION.tgz" "/opt/solr-$SOLR_VERSION.tgz.asc"); \
    gpg --batch --verify "/opt/solr-$SOLR_VERSION.tgz.asc" "/opt/solr-$SOLR_VERSION.tgz"; \
  else \
    echo "Skipping GPG validation due to non-Apache build"; \
  fi; \
  tar -C /opt --extract --file "/opt/solr-$SOLR_VERSION.tgz"; \
  (cd /opt; ln -s "solr-$SOLR_VERSION" solr); \
  rm "/opt/solr-$SOLR_VERSION.tgz"*; \
  rm -Rf /opt/solr/docs/ /opt/solr/dist/{solr-core-$SOLR_VERSION.jar,solr-solrj-$SOLR_VERSION.jar,solrj-lib,solr-test-framework-$SOLR_VERSION.jar,test-framework}; \
  mkdir -p /opt/solr/server/solr/lib /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d /opt/docker-solr; \
  chown -R 0:0 "/opt/solr-$SOLR_VERSION"; \
  find "/opt/solr-$SOLR_VERSION" -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0755; \
  find "/opt/solr-$SOLR_VERSION" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0644; \
  chmod -R 0755 "/opt/solr-$SOLR_VERSION/bin" "/opt/solr-$SOLR_VERSION/contrib/prometheus-exporter/bin/solr-exporter" /opt/solr-$SOLR_VERSION/server/scripts/cloud-scripts; \
  cp /opt/solr/bin/solr.in.sh /etc/default/solr.in.sh; \
  mv /opt/solr/bin/solr.in.sh /opt/solr/bin/solr.in.sh.orig; \
  mv /opt/solr/bin/solr.in.cmd /opt/solr/bin/solr.in.cmd.orig; \
  chown root:0 /etc/default/solr.in.sh; \
  chmod 0664 /etc/default/solr.in.sh; \
  mkdir -p /var/solr/data /var/solr/logs; \
  (cd /opt/solr/server/solr; cp solr.xml zoo.cfg /var/solr/data/); \
  cp /opt/solr/server/resources/log4j2.xml /var/solr/log4j2.xml; \
  find /var/solr -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0770; \
  find /var/solr -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0660; \
  sed -i -e "s/\"\$(whoami)\" == \"root\"/\$(id -u) == 0/" /opt/solr/bin/solr; \
  sed -i -e 's/lsof -PniTCP:/lsof -t -PniTCP:/' /opt/solr/bin/solr; \
  chown -R "0:0" /opt/solr-$SOLR_VERSION /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d /opt/docker-solr; \
  chown -R "$SOLR_USER:0" /var/solr; \
  { command -v gpgconf; gpgconf --kill all || :; }; \
  rm -r "$GNUPGHOME"

COPY --chown=0:0 scripts /opt/docker-solr/scripts
RUN chmod -R +x /opt/docker-solr/scripts/*



COPY ${JAR_FILE} /server/solr-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/testing.jar

VOLUME /var/solr
EXPOSE 8983
WORKDIR /opt/solr
USER $SOLR_USER
RUN echo $PATH
RUN ls -ltr /opt/docker-solr/scripts
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["solr-foreground"]
```

Comment: It looks like you declared that directory as a `VOLUME`; why?  (Mostly Dockerfile `VOLUME` has only confusing side effects, and you can safely remove it without any particular consequence.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy the jar file into the docker image when you're building it.

```
COPY <PATH TO YOUR JAR ON MACHINE> <PATH TO THE JAR YOU WANT IN THE DOCKER IMAGE>
```

This will copy the file from the host machine into the docker image's directory.

```
COPY target/jts-core-1.15.0-javadoc.jar target/jts-core-1.15.0-javadoc.jar
```

The above example will `COPY` the `jts-core-1.15.0-javadoc.jar` file present in your current path's `target` directory into the docker image's `target` directory.

Post that the command for `ARGS` and `ADD` should work as expected.

```
COPY target/jts-core-1.15.0-javadoc.jar target/jts-core-1.15.0-javadoc.jar
ARG JAR_FILE=target/jts-core-1.15.0-javadoc.jar
ADD  ${JAR_FILE} /server/solr-webapp/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/testing.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

***UPDATE***

After a while of playing around with the docker file, I have figured out the problem.

I will update the Dockerfile above also.

I did not need to create a VOLUME in my docker-file as it was not needed.

I added the below line that copied my .jar file without removing the previous files

```
COPY <Your jar file>/opt/solr-$SOLR_VERSION/<Input path here where to copy jar file"
```